# Formula for number of faces in 4 dimensions

Tags: general-topology, geometry, closed-form, dimension-theory-analysis

If a polytope has $m$ faces in 3 dimensions, how many faces does its analogous polytope have in four dimensions?  Does a formula exist?

For example, if $m=4$, you have a tetrahedron, and the 4-simplex has 10 faces.  If $m=6$, you have a cube, and the tesseract has 24 faces.  I know that formulas exist to find the number of m-cubes within the boundaries of an n cube, but what I'm asking is how to find the number of faces of any polytope given *only* $m$.

Comment: One problem with your question is that some polytopes in dimension $m$ do not have a natural corresponding polytope in dimension $n$ when $m \neq n.$

Comment: I think you need to clarify if you are talking about the same polytope or the $n$-dimensional analogue.  For example, a 3D tetrahedron in 4D is still just a 3D tetrahedron.  A cube in 4D is still a cube.  You seem to be converting into some corresponding higher dimensional shape.

Comment: I'm talking about its analogue.  Like the examples stated, I'm going from a 3-simplex to a 4-simplex or a 3-cube to a 4-cube.

Comment: I know that not all polytopes have corresponding higher dimensional polytopes, but there must exist some sort of insight as to how the number of faces change as you go up a dimension...

Comment: Certain ones are definitely known, for example: https://oeis.org/A001788

Comment: @AliAbdulla: have you read my answer to your question? What kind of "insight" are you looking for?

Comment: Your answer told me exactly what I needed to know.  I incorrectly assumed that there was a single procedure by which to obtain a higher dimensional analogous polytope, but you have shown me there is not.  Thanks for the answer, and for pointing me in the right direction by mentioning affine spans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different processes that let you go from a 3-dimensional polytope to an "analogous" 4-dimensional polytope. To get from a 3-simplex to a 4-simplex you take a join with a point outside the affine span of the 3-simplex. To get from a 3-cube to a 4-cube you take the product with a unit interval. To get from 3-dimensional octahedron to the 4-dimensional "generalised octahedron" that is the unit ball in $\Bbb{R}^4$ under the 1-norm, you take the join with 2 points outside the affine span of the 3-dimensional octahedron. These processes have a different effect on the number of faces, so there is no single formula to calculate the number of faces in the 4-dimensional polytope from the 3-dimensional polytope.